# What's the difference between ἀγάπη and στοργή?

Tags: greek

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_words_for_love ἀγάπη, among other things, refers to

> **Agape is used in ancient texts to denote feelings for one's children** and the feelings for a spouse

while στοργή is explained like this:

> Storge means "love, affection" and "especially of parents and
>   children".[10] It is the common or natural empathy, like that felt by
>   parents for offspring.

Sounds very similar (other meanings of the words are different). That these words share this meaning kind of contradicts the main point of this article

> Ancient Greek philosophy differentiates at least four main conceptual
>   forms and distinct words for the Modern English word love

Comment: It may be good to have a look at C.S. Lewis in *The Four Loves*, because he revives storage as one of those “four loves” and references the classical sources.

Answer (score 4):

***στοργή***  derives from the verb [στέργω](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%83%CF%84%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%B3%CF%89#Ancient_Greek),  whose etymology

> From Proto-Indo-European *sterg- (literally “to cover, to protect”)

may well give a clue to the connotation of *protectiveness* associated with the word.

So, στοργή summarizes the feelings of parents to offspring, but not vice versa (unless in the declining years of the former). My sense is that ἀγάπη is quite symmetric in this setup.

στοργή  has a strong sense of familial affection. In early Christianity, the conceit of moving from ἀγάπη to στοργή suggested acquiring new quasi-family ties.

Comment: I never associated στοργή with early Christianity (in fact, I believe the word doesn't occur in the NT). What exactly do you mean by your last sentence?

Comment: [Romans 12.20](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0155%3Abook%3DRomans%3Achapter%3D12%3Averse%3D10). [See](https://books.google.com/books?id=i1c7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA223&dq=Paul++Romans+XII++8-11&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_l87YtojlAhUGC6wKHcvTBsIQ6AEwBHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=Paul%20%20Romans%20XII%20%208-11&f=false).

Answer (score 0):

**Storge** (*Στοργή*) refers to the expression of **Agape** (*Ἀγάπη*) (but other types of *loves* too). In other words Storge is an act of, and Agape the feeling of. One cannot be feeling *Storge* (not in Greek (1), yes in English for *affection* and *fondness*), just express it.

(1) well, ok, maybe it can sometimes be worded as feeling it, but it really is strongly expression oriented.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this?

Comment: No, sorry I should have specified that this is entirely anecdotal.